# Error when looping: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex

Tags: r, loops, storage, extract

I am new in coding with R and I work with a large dataset.
I am trying to write a code that do the following things:

1. Get all pathes to all files in my folder
2. Extract the names of the files (as I want to name my plots after the input file)
3. Read in all files in my folder (these are all .csv files)
4. Plot a diagram for each .csv file by plotting groundwater level against the year
   --> these plots should then get the title of the input file and also be stored under the same name.

For example when my file is called 211210.csv, then the title should be 211210 and stored as 211210.png

This is the code I have until know. As I said, I am new to R, and I tried to solve may problems I had in the code but I still run into new errors. Is there someone who can explain me where the problem is and how to solve it.

```
library(fs)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

#Opening path to my data

filepath <- fs::dir_ls("D:/Desktop/Masterarbeit/Daten/Test/")

# Get name of files 
name <- basename(filepath) 


#Read every single files 
file_content <- list()

for (i in seq_along(filepath)){
  path <- filepath
  
  file_content[[i]] <- read.csv(
    file = filepath[[i]], header = TRUE
    
    )
}

file_content <- set_names(file_content, filepath)


#Plot the diagram with gwl against year for each file, title = name of each file and store it in a seperat folder with the name of the input file

for (i in file_content){
  mypath <- file.path("D:/Desktop/Masterarbeit/Daten/Results/", paste("Messstelle_", name[[i]], ".png", sep = ""))
  png(file=mypath)
    mytitle = paste("Messstelle", name[[i]])
  plot(i$year, i$gwl,
     pch = 19, #--> solid circle
     cex = 1.5, #--> make 150% size
     main = name[[i]],
     xlab = "Year",
     ylab = "Ground water level",
)
  dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would prefer doing everything in one loop for efficiency. Second, I would avoid using unnecessary packages, e.g. fs (Base R has a good `list.files` function to list all files in a folder) Third, I would iterate through the names of the files and not through a numeric vector, e.g.:

```
filepath <- "D:/Desktop/Masterarbeit/Daten/Test/"
files <- list.files(filepath, pattern=".csv")

#Iterate through every single file 
for (file in files){
  
  name2store <- strsplit(file, "[.]")[[1]][1]
  
  path2read <- file.path(filepath, file) 
  data <- read.csv(file =path2read, header = TRUE)
 
  mypath <- file.path("D:/Desktop/Masterarbeit/Daten/Results/", paste("Messstelle_", name2store, ".png", sep = ""))
  
  png(file=mypath)
  mytitle = paste("Messstelle", name2store)
  plot(data$year, data$gwl,
       pch = 19, #--> solid circle
       cex = 1.5, #--> make 150% size
       main = name2store,
       xlab = "Year",
       ylab = "Ground water level",
  )
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. So I basically should have used different functions. Just for understanding, can you tell me why I run with my code in an error and how I could have solved it? I want to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Which error message do you get when running your code version?

Comment: This one: Error in name[[i]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex

Comment: you define `name <- basename(filepath)`in your code and afterward, you are assessing elements of `name` as it would be a `list()` via `name[[i]]`.  This does not work. You should work with the `ì` in your for-loop itself to extract the `name2store`.